# Why can't I use <Class>.this in anonymous class?

Tags: java, oop, anonymous, anonymous-class

I recently use this code, and realize that in anonymous class, I can't access the instance by .this, like this:

```
Sprite sprFace = new Sprite() {

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondElapsed) {
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        protected void run() {    
            Sprite.this.getParent().detach(Sprite.this); // Here
        }});
    }

};
```

I know how to solve it (just declare a "me" variable), but I need to know why I can't use `<Class>.this`?

Comment: @Thilo Sorry I have a typo mistake. me will return the Runnable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<Class>.this` syntax gives a special way of referring to the object of type `<Class>`, as opposed to the shadowing type.

In addition, `<Class>` must be the name of the type you're trying to access. In your case, `Sprite` is *not* the actual type of `sprFace`. Rather, `sprFace` is an instance of an anonymous *subclass* of `Sprite`, thus the syntax is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the outer object is not `Sprite`, but rather an anonymous subclass of `Sprite` and you have no way of naming this anonymous subclass in your code.

In this case you need a name to refer to and therefore an anonymous class will not do the job. You can use a local class instead (which behaves as an anonymous class with a name). In the code block, you can write:

```
class MySprite extends Sprite {

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondElapsed) {
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
            MySprite.this.getParent().detach(MySprite.this); // Here
        });
    }

};

Sprite sprFace = new MySprite();
```

Comment: But that would be the same as just saying `this.getParent()` or `getParent()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd rather declare me variant.

Comment: W.N.: I don't know what you mean by 'declare me variant'.

Comment: Thile: No. Notice that there is an anonymous `Runnable` inside the anonymous `Sprite`. `this` would refer to the `Runnalbe` instance.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. `private Sprite me = this`

Comment: @Mathias. Okay maybe. But without the `this`, any `getParent` from parent or containing class should be accessible unless shadowed.

Comment: @Thilo: But you can't use get the object for the method parameter.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, but it could be shadowed. We cannot tell from the code given and there is probably a reason why W.N. asks...

Comment: The reason he asked was more for the method parameter, I think.