# Access an Anonymous or Local Inner Class Within an Anonymous or Local Inner Class

Tags: java, class, local, anonymous

Okay, so I know how to access the outer class that encloses an inner class, whether its anonymous or inner.

But my question is, how to access the outer class if it itself **is** an inner class? Some code to help:

```
public final class LocationPage extends BasePage {
    private static final String CRITERIA_FORM_ID = "CriteriaForm";
    protected Panel onCreateBodyPanel() {
        return new ViewBodyPanel(BasePage.BODY_PANEL_ID) {
            public void invokeMe() {
                // How do I Invoke This Method?
            }

            private Form<CriteriaBean> helpCreateCriteriaForm() {
                return new Form<CriteriaBean>(LocationPage.CRITERIA_FORM_ID) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit() {
                        LocationPage.this.ViewBodyPanel.invokeMe(); // Compile Error.
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** For those wanting to see what I am trying to do here, here is a complete code sample. This is actually Apache Wicket specific but I think you can get the idea. Have a look at a method named **onSubmit**. I added a code comment to help pinpoint it.

**UPDATE TWO:** Made the code sample to the point. Sorry about that!

Comment: @KublaiKhan Yeah, I realize my code sample was not a good indicator of what I wanted to do. I posted some updated code.

Comment: I'm interested, but could you please narrow this down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so it's easier for us to help you? Eliminate unrelated code and just show us the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. Made the code more to the point.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103087/why-cant-i-use-class-this-in-anonymous-class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to specify ParentClass.this.something to disambiguate. If your Form does not have a method invokeMe, you can simply use the name without qualifying, and the compiler should find it:

```
        private Form<CriteriaBean> helpCreateCriteriaForm() {
            return new Form<CriteriaBean>(LocationPage.CRITERIA_FORM_ID) {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit() {
                    invokeMe();
                }
            };
        }
```

If the function does exist in the inner-inner class as well, there's no trick in Java to do it. Rather rename or wrap your ViewBodyPanel.invokeMe method into something that is unambiguous.

```
  public void vbpInvokeMe(){
     invokeMe();
  }
  private Form<CriteriaBean> helpCreateCriteriaForm() {
        return new Form<CriteriaBean>(LocationPage.CRITERIA_FORM_ID) {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                vbpInvokeMe();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Seems that this does it. Was kind of hoping there was another way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Okay, so I know how to access the outer class that encloses an inner
>   class, whether its anonymous or inner.

**If you are using inner classes** than you can do the following

```
public class A{
   public void printHello(){
      System.out.println("Hello!");
   }
   class B{
      public void accessA(){
         A.this.printHello();
      }
   }
}
```